# A-Frame, ThreeJS reset gyroscope

Tags: android, ios, three.js, rotation, aframe

The idea is to make it possible for user to look at the object closer in special scene and communicate with it using rotation controls. So when user entering this scene his camera should be rotated straight on the object despite in what direction he was looking before. So this is workflow for interaction: User goes throw scene A -> User clicks on object -> Scene switching animation starts -> User and object got moved to some specific place (scene B) -> Camera rotations sets straight to new object position -> animation ends, user is watching closely on the object. The problem is that even if I use

`el.setAttribute('look-controls','false');
 el.setAttribute('rotation',{x:0,y:0,z:0});
 el.setAttribute('look-controls','true');`

and the user moves a phone just a little bit camera rotation would be set to its previous rotation from scene A. I think that's because our device is still physically in position looking on object in scene A. Maybe there are some ways to reset initial gyroscope values? So after switching to scene B '0 0 0' values for gyroscope would be set for physical position in which the phone is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to recenter / reset orientation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43576222/is-there-a-way-to-recenter-reset-orientation)

Comment: Would moving the object to place it in front of wherever the user is looking when entering the special scene be an option?

Answer (score 0):

Have a wrapper entity around the camera. When you want to reset your camera rotation, you set the wrapper entity's rotation, factoring in the current rotation of the camera so that you can cancel it out.

Dupe: [Is there a way to recenter / reset orientation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43576222/is-there-a-way-to-recenter-reset-orientation)